# Take a Console.ReadLine(); input and put it into a List<Int32>?

Tags: c#

heres a snip of some of what I have.C#FrameworkConsole app

```
namespace Arraylab
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please guess a number, zero if you must.");
            int guessedNumber = 1;

            try
            {
                guessedNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You did not make the right entry. Please hit Enter and try again.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            //This will end the program if its not a number that is entered. 

            List<Int32> guessedNumbers = new List<int>;


            guessedNumbers.AddRange(guessedNumber); //It wont accept this guessedNumber varriable.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Add instead of AddRange to add a single entry to a List

Comment: I declared the guessedNumber variable at the top in the class. But the list wont accept the variable as the variable being stored in the list.

Comment: Okay. Ill try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First: instead of `ConvertTo.Int32` and catching the exception, the better practice is to use `int.TryParse`, which returns false if the string cannot be parsed.  You can then eliminate the `try`.  Remember it is always better to *avoid* an exception than to *catch* an exception.

Second, if you *are* going to use exception handling, "pokemon handling" -- gotta catch them all -- is a bad practice when you know what exception you're expecting.  Catch the specific exception.

> It wont accept this guessedNumber variable.

```
guessedNumbers.AddRange(guessedNumber);
```

`AddRange` adds a *sequence of elements* to a list, not a single element. Use `Add` to add a single element to the end of a list.

Comment: @RufusL: That is bizarre. I don't know, and I don't have time to dig into it, but I left an educated guess on the answer posted.

Answer (score -1):

Use add instead of addrange. This will accept an int

Edit: how is this not a correct answer?